# How to indent items of a sublist using css and html in wordpress

Tags: html, wordpress, css

I hava a nested  and the bullets change but the actual indentions of the text don't, it looks like this...
http://104.236.190.78/partners/

I have want the physical bullets to be moved.  I tried using   or something like that but it just messed it up.  Any help is greatly appriceated thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add `padding-left` to the second `<ul>` element, which will indent the bullets as well as the text. Something like `padding-left: 20px` or `padding-left: 30px` should do the trick.

Or, even better, you could create a css class. Something like

```
.nested-list {
    padding-left: 30px;
}
```

and add that class to the nested list.

Answer (score -1):

It's simple .Add `padding-left: 25px;`  to the second  tag and it will do the trick